# When reciting the Quran, what is the proper pronunciation of the Arabic letter ط?

Tags: quran, arabic, pronunciation

Salam, when I say the letter ط air comes out, and when are reading Qur’an, air should not be coming out of our mouths. What should be the position of my tongue?

Answer (score 1):

For ط, the front section of your tongue should be touching the back of your top front teeth. If you emphasize the sound, your cheeks will blow up.

Comment: When doing ـِ I’m still pulling out air when pronouncing the Kasrah

Comment: Kasrah and dammah are harder than fathah, so your struggles are normal. They take time and practice. Try pronouncing it softer with dammah and kasrah. Good luck.